# RequireJS: Dependency Loop?

Tags: requirejs

I have a question related to RequireJS as I am newbie using it. I understand it includes adding dependencies in module (JS files) by including the dependency in `define`. Lets say I have two files file1.js and file2.js and both dependent on each other. What would happen if I do the following:

file1.js

```
define(SomeDependency 1, file2, ..., SomeDependency N){
}
```

file2.js

```
define(SomeDependency 1, file1, ..., SomeDependency N){
}
```

Would the above code create some error like dependency loop or some other javascript error?

Comment: You can read about it [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular)!

Comment: Thanks for the link. It clarifies my confusion.